# jQuery Browser Compatibility (IE)

Tags: php, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, compatibility

Since the source code I am trying to show you is rather long and complex, I am simply going to provide a link to the page I am having troubles with.

http://www.thesportinghub.com/lms/make-my-picks

If you work with this script in Google Chrome or the latest versions of Firefox (5 or 6), you will notice how the jQuery in this script is intended to work. It works exactly how I want it to work in those browsers.

However, I am currently having trouble figuring out why it is not working correctly in IE6, IE7, and IE8... I am willing to say "whatever" to IE6, but I am really hoping to get this to work in IE7 and IE8. By viewing my source code, is there anything you can see that is causing the problems in IE7 and IE8.

The main issue (as you will notice after you play with the jQuery in Chrome, and then in IE), is that when a team is clicked, it will disable the input field and put a strike through that team throughout the rest of the weeks. However, the input is disabling correctly in IE, but the strike (addClass in jQuery) is not working.

I am willing to provide more information.... I don't want to overload info quite yet. But this has been an issue I have been struggling to fix for a few hours now.

Thank you in advance for your help. I will accept the best answer and vote up! Thanks!

**UPDATES WITH CODE ARE BELOW**

Here is my current javascript/jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.radio:checked').addClass("selected");
    $('.pickbox').text($('.radio:checked').val());

    var selected_week = $('#weekselect').val();

    $('table.weekbox').hide();
    $('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
    $('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');


    $('input.radio').change(function () {
        $('.teambox').find('span.strike').removeClass('strike');
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var us_selected = selected.replace(/ /g, "");

        $('.radio:not(:checked)').removeClass('selected');
        $('.radio:not(:checked)').next('span').css('color', '');
        $('.radio:not(:checked)').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.radio:checked').addClass('selected');
        $('.pickbox').text($(this).val());
        $('.pickbox').css('border', '3px dashed #88cc33');
        //$('.pickbox').text($('.teambox').find('span.' + us_selected).text());
        $('.teambox').find('span.' + us_selected).addClass('strike');

        $('.selected').each(function () {
            var selected_team = $(this).val();
            var x_selected_team = selected_team.replace(/ /g, "");
            $('.teambox').find('span.' + x_selected_team).text(selected_team).addClass('strike');
            $('table.weekbox').find('td input[value="' + selected_team + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.selected').next('span').css('color', '#88cc33');
        });
    });


    $('#weekselect').change(function () {
        var selected_week = $('#weekselect').val();

        if ($('input[name="Week' + selected_week + '"]').is(':not(:checked)')) {
            $('table.weekbox').hide();
            $('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
            $('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');
            $('.pickbox').css('border', '1px dashed #FFFFFF');
            $('.pickbox').text('');
        }

        $('table.weekbox').hide();
        $('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
        $('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');
        $('input:not(:checked)').next('span').removeClass('strike');
        $('input[disabled]:not(:checked)').next('span').addClass('strike');

        $('.pickbox').text($('input.radio[name="Week' + selected_week + '"].selected').val());

        if ($('.pickbox').text() != "") {
            $('.pickbox').css('border', '3px dashed #88cc33');
        }

        $('.selected').each(function () {
            var selected_team = $(this).val();
            var x_selected_team = selected_team.replace(/ /g, "");
            $('.teambox').find('span.' + x_selected_team).text(selected_team).addClass('strike');
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Here is some of the DOM elements this jQuery should be affecting:

```
<table id="weekbox1" class="weekbox" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#000000" width="100%"> 
<tr> 
<td class="three" colspan="4">Week 1</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="one">Date</td> 
<td class="one">Away Team</td> 
<td class="one">Home Team</td> 
<td class="one">Time (EST)</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/08/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="New Orleans Saints" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New Orleans Saints"></input> 
    <span>New Orleans Saints</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Green Bay Packers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Green Bay Packers"></input> 
    <span>Green Bay Packers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">8:30 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Atlanta Falcons" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Atlanta Falcons"></input> 
    <span>Atlanta Falcons</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Chicago Bears" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Chicago Bears"></input> 
    <span>Chicago Bears</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Cincinnati Bengals" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Cincinnati Bengals"></input> 
    <span>Cincinnati Bengals</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Cleveland Browns" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Cleveland Browns"></input> 
    <span>Cleveland Browns</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Buffalo Bills" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Buffalo Bills"></input> 
    <span>Buffalo Bills</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Kansas City Chiefs" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Kansas City Chiefs"></input> 
    <span>Kansas City Chiefs</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Philadelphia Eagles" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Philadelphia Eagles"></input> 
    <span>Philadelphia Eagles</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="St  Louis Rams" class="radio" name="Week1" value="St  Louis Rams"></input> 
    <span>St. Louis Rams</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Tennessee Titans" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Tennessee Titans"></input> 
    <span>Tennessee Titans</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Jacksonville Jaguars" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Jacksonville Jaguars"></input> 
    <span>Jacksonville Jaguars</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Pittsburgh Steelers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Pittsburgh Steelers"></input> 
    <span>Pittsburgh Steelers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Baltimore Ravens" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Baltimore Ravens"></input> 
    <span>Baltimore Ravens</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Indianapolis Colts" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Indianapolis Colts"></input> 
    <span>Indianapolis Colts</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Houston Texans" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Houston Texans"></input> 
    <span>Houston Texans</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Detroit Lions" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Detroit Lions"></input> 
    <span>Detroit Lions</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Tampa Bay Buccaneers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Tampa Bay Buccaneers"></input> 
    <span>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">1:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="New York Giants" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New York Giants"></input> 
    <span>New York Giants</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Washington Redskins" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Washington Redskins"></input> 
    <span>Washington Redskins</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">4:15 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Carolina Panthers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Carolina Panthers"></input> 
    <span>Carolina Panthers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Arizona Cardinals" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Arizona Cardinals"></input> 
    <span>Arizona Cardinals</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">4:15 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Minnesota Vikings" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Minnesota Vikings"></input> 
    <span>Minnesota Vikings</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="San Diego Chargers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="San Diego Chargers"></input> 
    <span>San Diego Chargers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">4:15 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Seattle Seahawks" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Seattle Seahawks"></input> 
    <span>Seattle Seahawks</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="San Francisco 49ers" class="radio" name="Week1" value="San Francisco 49ers"></input> 
    <span>San Francisco 49ers</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">4:15 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/11/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Dallas Cowboys" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Dallas Cowboys"></input> 
    <span>Dallas Cowboys</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="New York Jets" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New York Jets"></input> 
    <span>New York Jets</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">8:20 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/12/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="New England Patriots" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New England Patriots"></input> 
    <span>New England Patriots</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Miami Dolphins" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Miami Dolphins"></input> 
    <span>Miami Dolphins</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">7:00 PM</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="two">09/12/11</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Oakland Raiders" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Oakland Raiders"></input> 
    <span>Oakland Raiders</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two"> 
<input type="radio" id="Denver Broncos" class="radio" name="Week1" value="Denver Broncos"></input> 
    <span>Denver Broncos</span> 
</td> 
<td class="two">10:15 PM</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

**As mentioned above**, it is probably *easier* to visit the attached link (above) I have sent you all and try to look at the code first in Chrome (and see how it works how I expect it to work), and then try it in IE 6 - IE 8 and notice how it does not do everything I am wanting it to do.

Look forward to all the help you can provide me!

**UPDATE**

```
$('input[disabled]:not(:checked)').next('span').addClass('strike');
```

I think the above code is where my problem is coming up... is there something funky about making my attributes not read correctly in IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close your input tags correctly.

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New York Jets"></input> //Incorrect
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New York Jets" /> //Correct
```

Chrome seems to be smart enough to fix it and treat the `</input>` as part of the previous input element, but if you try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9GaX/1/) in IE, you can see it thinks `</input>` is the next tag.  `$("foo").next("span")` will only select the next element if it is a span.

http://jsfiddle.net/v9GaX/1/

Comment: Wow... if this is it... You are my hero Dennis.