# jQuery IE issues

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Browser Compatability (IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225849/jquery-browser-compatability-ie)

I would initially post some code snippets (and will if you request it), but I think this problem would be easier to identify if you follow this link and check out my problem firsthand. And, the code snippets could get rather lengthy.

Link: http://www.thesportinghub.com/lms/make-my-picks

If you open up this page in Google Chrome, IE9, Firefox 5.0+, or Safari, and if you click around a bit, you will notice how this page is INTENDED to function. It is working PROPERLY and PERFECTLY as I have drawn up in these browsers.

The problem I am facing is with jQuery compatability. When you select a radio button (while in one of the aforementioned browsers), it will cross out that respective team and disable the remaining radio buttons for that team throughout the rest of the weeks. You should see it cross out in two places in the "working" browsers.

However, jump to IE7 and IE8 and you will notice the same is not the case. I have looked up and down my code for basic syntax errors and have searched the web endlessly to solve this. I would much appreciate anyone's assistance with this.

I am willing to provide more information, code snippets, and be actively involved in trying to solve this issue I am having.

**UPDATE WITH CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.radio:checked').addClass("selected");
$('.pickbox').text($('.radio:checked').val());

var selected_week = $('#weekselect').val();

$('table.weekbox').hide();
$('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
$('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');


    $('input.radio').change(function () {
        $('.teambox').find('span.strike').removeClass('strike');
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var us_selected = selected.replace(/ /g, "");

        $('.radio:not(:checked)').removeClass('selected');
        $('.radio:not(:checked)').next('span').css('color','');
        $('.radio:not(:checked)').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.radio:checked').addClass('selected');
        $('.pickbox').text($(this).val());
        $('.pickbox').css('border','3px dashed #88cc33');
        //$('.pickbox').text($('.teambox').find('span.' + us_selected).text());
        $('.teambox').find('span.' + us_selected).addClass('strike');

    $('.selected').each(function () {
    var selected_team = $(this).val();
    var x_selected_team = selected_team.replace(/ /g, "");
    $('.teambox').find('span.' + x_selected_team).text(selected_team).addClass('strike');
    $('table.weekbox').find('td input[value="' + selected_team + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.selected').next('span').css('color','#88cc33');
    });
        });


  $('#weekselect').change(function () {
    var selected_week = $('#weekselect').val();

    if ($('input[name="Week' + selected_week + '"]').is(':not(:checked)')) {
        $('table.weekbox').hide();
        $('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
        $('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');
    $('.pickbox').css('border','1px dashed #FFFFFF');
    $('.pickbox').text('');
    }

        $('table.weekbox').hide();
        $('table#weekbox' + selected_week).show();
        $('span.selection.text').html('<br/>My Week ' + selected_week + ' Selection:');
        $('input:not(:checked)').next('span').removeClass('strike');
        $('input[disabled]:not(:checked)').next('span').addClass('strike');

    $('.pickbox').text($('input.radio[name="Week' + selected_week + '"].selected').val());

    if ($('.pickbox').text() != "") {
        $('.pickbox').css('border','3px dashed #88cc33');
    }

    $('.selected').each(function () {
    var selected_team = $(this).val();
    var x_selected_team = selected_team.replace(/ /g, "");
    $('.teambox').find('span.' + x_selected_team).text(selected_team).addClass('strike');
    });

});
});
</script>
```

There is my jQuery script... Someone has mentioned my IE problems are because my radio buttons are not being read from the .change function, and that it needed to be .click...

Comment: Wow... I mean, I am just trying to get some help... I do not see why people are so up in arms about this duplicate posting... They closed it on me.... I feel like this could be an issue people face in the future. Saying it is "too localized" is not a fair assessment of the issue.

Comment: I tried it in IE 7  and it crosses out that selected team.. I don't see what is not working.

Comment: It should cross out in two places... I know it is crossing out on the right side, but it should also be crossing out throughout the weeks.

Comment: The reason why the other question was closed because it's only on your site. We would have to dig into your site to see whats going wrong. If you could narrow down the problem to a few functions that don't act as expected, it's a different story, because then it's those few functions.

Comment: Fair enough, I will revise my post and provide specific code snippets, but im afraid it will be difficult to understand, but alright...

Comment: Let's go around and close every post where someone is trying to get help in a respectful and efficient manner and see how many developers continue to use this site.

Comment: I have modified my post with updated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `change` on the radio buttons instead of `click`.  IE needs the radio buttons to blur before firing the change event.  Also, be very careful using spaces in your element IDs.

Comment: Thank the lord, Dennis. After fighting the entire community, you are giving me a glimmer of hope. Thank you. I will try this solution.

Comment: Alright, Dennis, I changed it instead of .change event, to the .click event... still no bueno... Were you thinking this would be the way I would make it cross-compatabile?

Comment: Okay, I looked into it a bit more and the problem seems to be the input tags.  Try `<input type="radio" class="radio" name="Week1" value="New Orleans Saints" />` which is a self-closing tag.  IE seems to think that `$("input").next()` is a `</input>` tag.  Not sure why though.

Comment: You did it Dennis, you did it!